# How to create a custom chatbot using Dialog flow

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-messaging, artificial-intelligence, dialogflow-es, chatbot

I have developed a custom chatbot using dialog flow api and js.
Since the api returns unique json structure for different intents, I have to do so much validation to parse the value and display in front end.It also ends with the error like the same message is displayed multiple times .

To avoid these errors whether there is any simplest method to create the chatbot using dialog flow?

Whether I can use dialog flow sdk to make the development process simpler? If we can do so, can you share the steps that has to be followed ?

Answer (score 0):

There are various SDK's available for your front-end implementation.
And example of such an SDK can be found here: https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-dialogflow#readme

This library enables you to develop a chatbot a lot faster without a bunch of parsing.

An overview of all SDK's can be found in the documentation: https://dialogflow.com/docs/sdks#v2_client_libraries

If you encounter any issues with one of these SDK's, please specify this in your question or comment